# 4 Copies of my DLLs instead of just 1?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, dll

I have a solution with 2 projects.

Both projects need the same 4 DLL's.

I have a lib folder with the 4 DLL's in each project.

When the solution is compiled the 4 DLL's in each lib folder are copied to the bin folder.

Now, there are 4 sets of the same 4 DLL's.

I tried putting the DLLs in the bin directory but Visual Studio threw a lot of errors to that.

Is this how it is supposed to work? Ideally I'd like only one set, two max. Not sure where I should put my DLLs to fix this.

Comment: Why do you care that it copies the DLL's to each bin directory?  What really matters is where you install the DLL's in the release environment.  If you install both projects into the same folder, or install the DLL's into a common library folder (or the GAC), you only need one copy of each.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is how it's supposed to work.

You can adjust this process by changing the [CopyLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169644%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) property on your references to false.

Set it to true on your start-up project and to false on the other one.

Answer (score 3):

In each project you would reference them (right click on the project and "Add Reference").  Upon building of your solution or project, Visual Studio should automatically copy the required referenced dlls into the `/bin` directory for you.

As for multiple copies, since each project is typically autonomous, each one will have a set of the referenced dlls, however if Project A references Project B, and you're only using Project A (say Project B is a class library), then there should only be 6 dll's for project A.

```
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/projectA.dll
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/projectB.dll
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/shared1.dll
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/shared2.dll
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/shared3.dll
- ProjectA/bin/Debug/shared4.dll
```